# Condition in an inequality problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I recently encountered an equality with the condition that $a,b,c$ are positive reals and $\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{1}{1+a}\le 1.$ The solution says that this condition is equivalent to $a+b+c+2\le abc.$ But I have a hard time figuring out why. Can anyone show why the two conditions are the same?

Comment: What does cyc mean?

Comment: What are you summing over?

Comment: @Eric S. a,b and c. In other words the condition is $$\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}\le 1.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac1{1+a}+\frac1{1+b}+\frac1{1+c}\leq1$$
$$(1+b)(1+c)+(1+a)(1+c)+(1+a)(1+b)\leq(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$$
$$3+2(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca\leq 1+(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca+abc$$
$$\therefore a+b+c+2\leq abc$$

Comment: Ah, the nostalgia :)

Comment: Wonderful! Never expected to expand the condition :)

Comment: Yeah. "Just do it" :-)